# How to hide a section of fields using a checkbox?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

How to hide a section of fields using a checkbox in visualforce pages?

Comment: Are you looking to do this on the fly with javascript or using your apex controller and visualforce native functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Salesforce approach (keeping the page weight down etc.), you could do something like the following:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!theBool}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onChange" action="{!myAction}" rerender="theFieldsPanel"/>
</apex>

<apex:outputPanel id="theFieldsPanel">
    <apex:variable var="v" value="" rendered="{!theBool}">
        <apex:inputField value="{!someField"} rendered/>
        <!-- more fields etc. -->
    </apex:variable>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Note that I don't use the `rendered` attribute on the output panel itself, this is because if it's not rendered then it doesn't exist in the page, and as such, doesn't make for a good  `rerender` target! Now you just require a simple action on the controller (you could do any other logic in here if need be):

```
public Pagereference myAction()
{
    // any logic etc. goes here
    return null;
}
```

The benefit of doing things this way, as opposed to with javascript is that you can ensure that if the fields are hidden then values won't be sent back to the controller for the variables they're bound to. Simply hiding things with javascript would not have the same effect, so say the user typed something in one of the fields and then hid them, whatever he/she typed would still end up in the related controller variables.